# Merge two object arrays and remove duplicated objects then sort by column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, duplicates

I have the following two arrays of objects:

**First Array:** `$array1`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => Muhammad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => Ibrahim
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => Sumayyah
        )
)
```

**Second Array:** `$array2`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => Muhammad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103
            [name] => Yusuf
        )
)
```

I want to merge these two object arrays (removing all duplicates) and sorted according to `id`.

**Desired output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => Muhammad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => Sumayyah
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => Ibrahim
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103
            [name] => Yusuf
        )
)
```

Comment: Why does one of the object use `StaffId` rather than `id` ?

Comment: Thanks. Your indexes still look odd though (e.g $arr2 has 2 `0` index)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These 3 simple steps did the work:

```
//both arrays will be merged including duplicates
$result = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );
//duplicate objects will be removed
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $result)));
//array is sorted on the bases of id
sort( $result );
```

**Note:** Answer by @Kamran helped me come to this simple solution

Comment: If the objects are big, the serialization of the whole object is very inefficient ! Propably there is a better way which uses only ids

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

I am posting the entire code listing here now instead of the previously posted main code, printing both input and output. You can simply copy and paste this code to test.

```
<?php

function array_to_object($arr) {
    $arrObject = array();
    foreach ($arr as $array) {
        $object = new stdClass();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
        $arrObject[] = $object;
    }

    return $arrObject;
}

function super_unique($array)
{
    $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
    foreach ($result as $key => $value)  {
        if ( is_array($value) ) {
          $result[$key] = super_unique($value);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function merge_arrays($arr1, $arr2) {
    $arr1 = (array)$arr1;
    $arr2 = (array)$arr2;
    $output = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
    sort($output);
    return super_unique($output);
}

$array1 = array(
        array("id" => "100", "name" => "muhammad"), 
        array("id" => "102", "name" => "ibrahim"), 
        array("id" => "101", "name" => "summayyah"), 
    );
$array1 = array_to_object($array1);

print "<h3>Your array 1</h3>";
print "<pre>";
print_r($array1);
print "</pre>";

$array2 = array(
        array("id" => "100", "name" => "muhammad"), 
        array("id" => "103", "name" => "yusuf"), 
    );
$array2 = array_to_object($array2);

print "<h3>Your array 2</h3>";
print "<pre>";
print_r($array2);
print "</pre>";

$result = merge_arrays($array1, $array2);

print "<h3>Your desired output</h3>";
print "<pre>";
print_r($result);
print "</pre>";
```

it will output the following:

```
Your array 1
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => muhammad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => ibrahim
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => summayyah
        )

)

Your array 2
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => muhammad
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103
            [name] => yusuf
        )

)

Your desired output
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => muhammad
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => summayyah
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => ibrahim
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 103
            [name] => yusuf
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. By the end of `merge_arrays()` the arrays are merged, sorting is not working and then `super_unique()` doesn't work at all (can't understand why)

Comment: i wonder why it didn't work. i tested this script and it still runs fine for me.

Comment: i just updated my answer to include the entire code listing instead of the main code, so you can copy paste and test

Comment: Yes i guess `array_to_object` was missing

Answer (score 1):

Assignments:

1. Merge
2. Remove Duplicates
3. Sort by `id`

The good news is: **Assigning temporary keys using `id` values does all of the hard work for you.**  No serializing is needed.

- `array_merge()` joins the arrays together.
- `array_column()` with a `null` 2nd parameter leaves the objects unmodified and `id` as the 3rd parameter assigns the temporary keys.  Because arrays cannot have duplicate keys, duplicate objects are weeded out in this step.
- Now that we have keys, `ksort()` avoids calling the more convoluted `usort()` to sort by `id` ascending.
- Finally, call `array_values()` to re-index the resultant array (remove the temporary keys).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fpHpi))

```
$array1 = [
    (object) ['id' => 100, 'name' => 'Muhammad'],
    (object) ['id' => 102, 'name' => 'Ibrahim'],
    (object) ['id' => 101, 'name' => 'Sumayyah']
];

$array2 = [
    (object) ['id' => 100, 'name' => 'Muhammad'],
    (object) ['id' => 103, 'name' => 'Yusuf']
];

$merged_keyed = array_column(array_merge($array1,$array2), NULL, 'id');
ksort($merged_keyed);
var_export(array_values($merged_keyed));
```

Alternatively, you can filter one of the arrays to remove duplicates, then merge them, then sort them.  `sort()` will effectively order the rows by the `id` column because the rows have equal size and `id` is the element in first position.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/965IK))

```
$result = array_merge($array1, array_udiff($array2, $array1, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b));
sort($result);
var_export($result);
```