# How to make single array of two array object?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to make single array array object of two array object
I have the following two arrays of objects

How to make single array array object of two array object
I have the following two arrays of objects

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 25
                [authorityId] => 2
                [grantVillage] => test
                [agency] => test
                [certificate] => Panding
                [amount] => 50000
                [startDate] => 2015-12-08
                [endDate] => 2015-12-08
                [grantArea] => test
                [added_date] => 0000-00-00
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 26
                [authorityId] => 2
                [grantVillage] => testing2
                [agency] => testing
                [certificate] => Verified
                [amount] => 50000
                [startDate] => 1970-01-01
                [endDate] => 1970-01-01
                [grantArea] => test
                [added_date] => 0000-00-00
            )

    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => kandi Area
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => kandi Area
            )

    )
```

I want to make it:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => kandi Area
                [id] => 25
                [authorityId] => 2
                [grantVillage] => test
                [agency] => test
                [certificate] => Panding
                [amount] => 50000
                [startDate] => 2015-12-08
                [endDate] => 2015-12-08
                [grantArea] => test
                [added_date] => 0000-00-00
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => kandi Area
                [id] => 26
                [authorityId] => 2
                [grantVillage] => testing2
                [agency] => testing
                [certificate] => Verified
                [amount] => 50000
                [startDate] => 1970-01-01
                [endDate] => 1970-01-01
                [grantArea] => test
                [added_date] => 0000-00-00
            )

    )
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Desired output is already mentioned in the question.

Comment: **Duplicate Question**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877586/how-to-merge-two-arrays-of-object-in-php

Comment: This is not duplicate question please have a look again on both the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for this:

```
$combinedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Edit: Misunderstood your question, the following would work as you simply need to loop through array 2 and add these values to array 1:

```
<?php      
  $array1 = array (
    0 => array (
      "id" => "25",
      "authorityId" => "2",
    ),
    1 => array (
      "id" => "26",
      "authorityId" => "2",
    )
  );

  $array2 = array (
    0 => array ( 
      "name" => "kandi Area"
    ),
    1 => array ( 
      "name" => "kandi Area"
    )
  );

  foreach ($array2 as $array2Key => $array2ValuesArray) {
    # This works for serialized arrays:
    // $array1[$array2Key]['name'] = $array2ValuesArray['name']; 
    # However this does not relate to the OP which means that this will work for stdClass Objects:
    $array1[$array2Key]->name = $array2ValuesArray->name;
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array1);
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Edit: This results in the following output:

```
array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [id] => 25
    [authorityId] => 2
    [name] => kandi Area
  ),
  [1] => stdClass Object
  (
    [id] => 26
    [authorityId] => 2
    [name] => kandi Area
  )
)
```

Comment: I do not want to merge please check my question again.

Comment: its not working    Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @rakeshstellen See my edit of the output as it was 100% tested and working PHP 5.5.28.

Comment: in your answer you have array inside array but in my question  stdClass Object inside array.

Comment: yes its working but for array inside array not for stdClass Object inside array please check my question again

Comment: @rakeshstellen That's great - glad you figured this out. I've approved your edit so that people in the future might be helped by this. Don't forget to mark the answer as solved if you have found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two array objects and can get an array object by following this question :

[How to merge two arrays of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877586/how-to-merge-two-arrays-of-object-in-php)

Once you get the merge array object. You can convert the array object(std class) into array by this  code snippet :

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($ArrayObject),true);
```