# Returning missing results from many to many table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a table structure like following:

```
Brands => BrandUser <= Users
```

I need to get brands which have corresponding record in the BrandUser table and the ones which don't have corresponding record in BrandUser table...

I have tried the following query:

```
public function getUserBrands($userId) {
        $select = new Select();
        $select->from(array('bu' => $this->table));
        $select->join(array('b' => 'brands'), 'bu.brandId = b.id', array('id','name'));
        $select->join(array('u' => 'users'), 'u.id = bu.userId', array('id','username'),Select::JOIN_LEFT);
        $where = new Where();
        $where->equalTo("bu.userId",$userId);
        $select->where($where);
        return $this->branduserTable->selectWith($select)->toArray();
    }
```

But I only get users which HAVE corresponding record in the BrandUser table... I need to get the rest of the brands which don't have the corresponding value in BrandUser... How can I do this??

Comment: Try going at it by having `Brands` as the primary table. By using `BrandsUser` as the primary table, it's going to use that as the main reference.

Comment: Can you write an answer so that I can test it out if it works ??

Comment: @aynber's answer seems right.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't returns the result that I was hoping for...

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, I'm not familiar with Zend-Framework, so you may have to adapt this a bit. But you need to use `Brands` as the primary/first table, so that it can get all the records of that table first, then match it to the rest of the tables.

```
public function getUserBrands($userId) {
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from(array('b' => 'brands'));
    $select->join(array('bu' => $this->table), 'bu.brandId = b.id', array('id','name'),Select::JOIN_LEFT);
    $select->join(array('u' => 'users'), 'u.id = bu.userId', array('id','username'),Select::JOIN_LEFT);
    $where = new Where();
    $where->equalTo("bu.userId",$userId);
    $select->where($where);
    return $this->branduserTable->selectWith($select)->toArray();
}
```