# How to compare an array of objects, and merge the value of a shared property when there's a match?

Tags: php, class, oop

## Background

In a project I am working on, I have created a `Builder` class with a few methods that builds its objects in different ways. Let's call it `CompanyBuilder`.

`CompanyBuilder` has three objects its in charge of building: `Company`, `Employee` and `Skill`. Inside each assembly method it injects some dependencies inside each object.

## Objects

These are the objects its in charge of building, I realize there's four here, but there are three *main* objects.

```
class Company {
    public $name;
    public $employees = array();

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Person {
    public $name;
}

class Employee extends Person {
    public $job;
    public $skills = array();
}

class Skill {
    public $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

## Builder

There are three methods in the builder aimed to provide flexibility when building the objects. The one that generated this question looks like this:

```
$company = $companyBuilder->buildCompany(
    'Acme',
    $dependency,
    $employee,
    array(
        $skillOne,
        $skillTwo,
        $skillThree
    )
);
```

The result of this would be **one** company object, with **one** employee which has **one or many** skills. This approach meets a business goal. However, there is a problem.

## The Problem

The problem arises when I have different `Company` objects, that contain the same `name` property. I want to merge the employees into one `Company` object, if the `Company` names match.

I had the thought I could create a `mergeEmployees` method, that could take in an indeterminate amount of `Company` objects as arguments, that are captured using [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), which turns them into an **array of objects**. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877586/how-to-merge-two-arrays-of-object-in-php) and it hasn't worked for me.

I *want* to find a company, in that array, with the same name and merge it's employees. So if the args array looks like this:

```
Company Object
(
    [name] => Acme
    [employees] => Array
        (
            [0] => Employee Object
                (
                    [job] => Designer
                    [skills] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => web
                                )

                            [1] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => ui
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => Jacob
                )

        )

)
Company Object
(
    [name] => Scholastic
    [employees] => Array
        (
            [0] => Employee Object
                (
                    [job] => Developer
                    [skills] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => java
                                )

                            [1] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => c#
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => Steve
                )

        )

)
Company Object
(
    [name] => Acme
    [employees] => Array
        (
            [0] => Employee Object
                (
                    [job] => Designer
                    [skills] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => ux
                                )

                            [1] => Skill Object
                                (
                                    [name] => css
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => Jacob
                )

        )

)
```

**How would I do comparisons on this array of objects, find that the `Employee` Jacob should have his skills of 'UX' and 'CSS' and merge it (reliably) with those skills of his previous Employee object?**

I have tried using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) but it wasn't working for me --- could definitely have been misusing it since it's intended to:

> Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function

I would want to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) but it only passes me one item in the callback function, which isn't enough for a comparison. Unless I'm missing something.

What's the best way to do something like this?

Comment: _two objects that are the same but have a different properties_ Surely that is the definition of **not the same**

Comment: I had realized that shortly after posting, and made an edit to make the intent clearer.

Comment: What about the same employee in two different companies?

Comment: You should prevent the creation of a new object and just update the first one. The object reference will do the rest of the job to you.

Comment: @Luka In that case the Employee's skills wouldn't need to be merged since they're utilized in a different company.

Comment: Ok i'll write the answer for you now

Comment: @GabrielHeming How would something like that look? Currently the built object isn't stored in the builder. It's just manufactured, but there's no record of it, persay. Maybe you could write an answer to explain how your idea would work.

Comment: There's no much work to do, take a look at [IdentyMap](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html). It's a part of DataMapper pattern but has the principle to ensure only 1 instance of a group of objects. I'll try to do a example, but I can't do it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an implementation already in the `buildCompany` method:

```
function buildCompany($companyName, $employeeName, $skills){
    //let's say existing companies are in $companies array
    $existingCompany = false;

    foreach($companies as $key => $company){
        if($company->name === $companyName){
            $existingCompany = true;

            $existingEmployee = false;
            foreach($company->employees as $keyE => $employee){
                if($employee->name === $employeeName){
                    $existingEmployee = true;
                    $employee->skills = array_unique(array_merge($employee->skills, $skills), SORT_REGULAR); //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469803/php-merging-two-array-into-one-array-also-remove-duplicates
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!$existingEmployee){
                $company->employees[] = new Employee($employeeName, $skills); // add a constructor to the Employee, i see it's missing (or just not provided)
            }
        }
    }
    if(!$existingCompany){
        $temp = new Company($companyName);
        $temp->employees[] = new Employee($employeeName, $skills); // add a constructor to the Employee, i see it's missing (or just not provided)
        $companies[] = $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `[count($companies) - 1]->employees` bit doing? Is it simply just adding the employee to the last added company? It seems like it'd be better to: `$company = new Company($companyName); $company->employees[] = new Employee($employeeName, $skills); $companies[] = $company;` or something, otherwise that looks like what I'm looking for. I added a check for empty on the companies array before the first `foreach`.

Comment: Ok, i agree with both of your improvements, nice to see you understand the code :)

Comment: However, checking for an empty array isn't necessary because foreach does that for you already

Comment: True, if it's initialized properly. ;)